# Format DateTime to UTC with FileHelpers

Tags: c#, datetime, filehelpers

I have a record that I write out to a CSV file using FileHelpers. I want the DateTime fields of the structure to be written out as the UTC date. I currently have the following formatter:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")]
```

What do I need to do to get it to output the UTC date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc says :

> You can check all the supported format
>   strings check the MSDN docs for
>   DateTime.ParseExact

So according to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "u")]

"u" => "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
It doesn't convert the date to utc, just format it

You still need DateTime.ToUniversalTime to convert it.

**Edit**
If you have something like :

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy" )]
public DateTime ShippedDate;
```

Then add a temp ShippedDateUTC :

```
public DateTime ShippedDate;

[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy" )]
public DateTime ShippedDateUTC {
  get{ return ShippedDate.ToUniversalTime();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives Attribute 'FieldConverter' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.

Comment: I just used the ToUniversalTime() before writing the record and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the transformation with a public setter that assigns the right value to a private field. For example:

```
public class OutputRecord
{
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy" )]
    private DateTime dateInUtc:

    public void SetDate(DateTime date)
    {
        dateInUtc = date.ToUniversalTime();
    }

}
```

You can also use a custom converter http://www.filehelpers.com/example_customconv.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) method of the DateTime class

So, if the `ConverterKind.Date` is of type DateTime your code should be

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date.ToUniversalTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ConverterKind.Date is not of type DateTime.